# PHP WAMP .HTACCESS How to rewrite URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've the following URL:
http://www.domain.com/content/index.php?filename=download-file.zip&visitorid=abcd&visitorval=xyz

And I want to access this script using the URL as following:
http://www.domain.com/content/download-file.zip?visitorid=abcd&visitorval=xyz

I've enabled rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and I've added an ".htaccess" file to the "content" subdirectory above, but couldn't write the rules to use at the .htaccess file to get the above redirect working.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your **`/content/.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sites/some.domain.com/content/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?filename=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your super-quick response :)
I've tried this, it gave me different results than what I've but it did not work.

Let me add more details:
My full URL is:
http://localhost/sites/some.domain.com/content/index.php?filename=MicroStrategy_Proposal_Timeline.zip&param1=val1&param2=val2

And I want to use it as:
http://localhost/sites/some.domain.com/content/MicroStrategy_Proposal_Timeline.zip&param1=val1&param2=val2

When I used your code above, it is redirecting me to the http://localhost/index.php

Comment: Note: I want also to support different file extensions [zip, rar, doc etc...]

Comment: ok you should have provided these details in the question itself to get better answer. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks!!!! This works great on my localhost.

Can we make it more dynamic, because when we publish this to live the URLs will be like:
http://some.domain.com/content/index.php?filename=MicroStrategy_Proposal_Timeline.zip&param1=val1&param2=val2
http://some.domain.com/content/MicroStrategy_Proposal_Timeline.zip&param1=val1&param2=val2

Where also the "some.domain.com" value is dynamic [we have several domains which are generated dynamically]

Comment: Ok you can try commenting out `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: Hi, Now I want to publish this to our live server, however it uses lighttpd webserver not Apache.
So, can you help me to convert the rewrite rules above to be written in lighttpd?

Comment: Actually I don't know much about `lighthttpd` request you to create a new question here on SO to get many more answers.